# Whose days are numbered, according to the players?

Tags: plot-explanation, mollys-game

Molly,while running a poker game, listened to the players talk about China's telecom firms
and their intention to collaborate, as well as their spending of $30 million on an outfielder
who had a .320 batting average and 110 RBIs. The players also noted that the telecom firms
control the market and select the artists they want to support:

> Players: They mind spending $10 million on a pitcher who is 8-14 this season.
> It's going to be Gephardt. They're all very excited about a company called Twitter.
> Unregulated money. Usually all cash. Unreported. His days are numbered. **His days are numbered**.
> I don't know how much longer she's going to be in that job. She's done. She's gone.

Whose days are numbered, according to the players?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't know and, in terms of the plot, it's not important.

The sequence is of players **at different games** talking amongst themselves.

Molly is listening to their insider knowledge in the hopes of gaining inside information as to finance or sports.

> MOLLY: Poker was my Trojan horse into the
> highest levels of finance,
> technology, politics, art,
> entertainment--all I had to do was
> listen.
>
> SERIES OF SHOTS--**Different games on different nights** as MOLLY
> listens to conversations between players and Googles various
> things she hears
>
> {snip}
>
> PLAYER #2
> His days are numbered.
>
> DIFFERENT GAME
> PLAYER #3
> His days are numbered.
>
> DIFFERENT GAME
> PLAYER #4
> I don’t know how much longer she’s
> gonna be in that job.
>
> DIFFERENT GAME
> PLAYER #3
> They’re very excited about a
> company called Twitter.
>
> DIFFERENT GAME
> PLAYER #2
> He’s done.
>
> DIFFERENT GAME
> PLAYER #5
> She’s gone.